# How do I create a self-referential association table rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

Say I have a table `products` and want to maintain `similar_products` for each product.

Answer (score 4):

This is the migration for the self-referential table.

```
create_table :similar_products, id: false do |t|
      t.references :product, foreign_key: true, null: false
      t.references :similar_product, foreign_key: { to_table: :similar_products }
    end
```

Answer (score 4):

```rb
class SimilarProductRelation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :similar_product, class_name: "Product"
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  # self being the "origin"
  has_many :similar_products_relations, source: :product_id, class_name: "SimilarProductRelation"
  has_many :similar_products, class_name: "Product", through: :similar_products_relations

  # self being the "destination"
  has_many :similar_products_relations_as, source: :similar_product_id, class_name: "SimilarProductRelation"
  has_many :similar_products_as, class_name: "Product", through: :similar_products_relations
end

# migration
create_table :similar_product_relations do |t|
  t.references :product, foreign_key: true, null: false, index: true
  t.references :similar_product, foreign_key: { to_table: :products }, null: false, index: true 
end
```

Index true or not depending on which direction you're going to make queries, and you can only keep one direction in the association, in the `Product` class, if you're only going to use one.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following ways :

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product, :class_name => 'Product'
   has_many :similar_products, :class_name => 'Product', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
end
```

The migrations can be added as :

```
add_column :products, :parent_id, :integer, null: true, index: true
add_foreign_key :products, :products, column: :parent_id
```