# Rails bi-directional / self join, populate form and show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

Problem: I have a model `Exercise`, this model can have exercises that are variations of each other. So a self join table I thought.

Like a join table of `Foo, Boo, Coo`, where `Foo` and `Boo` are models link by the joining table `Coo` allows for `@foo.boo` and `@boo.foo`

So I looked and read these posts describing bi and uni directional relation ships [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56617857/how-do-i-create-a-self-referential-association-table-rails-migration), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168442/many-to-many-relationship-with-the-same-model-in-rails). So the table stores the data correctly but now I'm have trouble on creating the correct query.

**EDIT:**

After reading more on how a `join table` works and naming conventions I see that the methods are working like they should. ***My question should*** be about how do I not cause `if statements` in the `show` and `form` page.

The way that it is set, if I was editing `object a` that had a relation to `object b` it would populate via the `@a.variations`. However, if I go to `object b` I have to get the relation via `@b.exercises` which does not seem correct but works. Further more, the same idea would have to be repeated on the `show` page. How does one go about making this a uniform "call" i.e. @a.variations and @b.variations to populate the `forms` and the `show`? Is it even possible?

**UPDATE/Clarification:** To question below regarding variations.

If there are many objects that are referenced, i.e. `A` is a variation of `B` and `C` is a variation of `B` then `A` would also be a variation of `C`. So a query of `@a.variations = [B,C]`; `@b.variations = [A,C]`; `@c.variations = [A,B]`. Hopefully this clarifies the question and my thinking behind this relation/query.

(extra info)- The reason being some people wont be able to squat so they will have to start with a different exercise that target the same muscles and build there way up to the squat. Or you could have been injured or on a recovery day and to target the muscles with a less complex movement.

Schema migration, Models, Controllers, Forms:

```
create_table :exercise_variation_relations do |t|
  t.references :exercise, foreign_key: true, null: false, index: true
  t.references :exercise_variation, foreign_key: { to_table: :exercises }, null: false, index: true 
end

class ExerciseVariationRelation < ApplicationRecord
        belongs_to :exercise, foreign_key: "exercise_id", class_name: "Exercise" 
        belongs_to :exercise_variation, foreign_key: "exercise_variation_id", class_name: "Exercise" 
    end

class Exercise < ApplicationRecord
**other code
        has_many :exercise_drills, foreign_key: :exercise_variation_id, class_name: "ExerciseVariationRelation"
        has_many :exercises, through: :exercise_drills, source: :exercise
    
     
has_many :variation_exercises, foreign_key: :exercise_id, class_name: "ExerciseVariationRelation"
has_many :variations, through: :variation_exercises, source: :exercise_variation

    validates_associated: :variation_exercises
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :variation_exercises

    ** other code
    end

Contoller 
params.fetch(:exercise, {}).permit( **other params
                                   variation_exercises_attributes: [:id, :exercise_variation_id, :_destroy], )

Form
   <%= f.fields_for :variation_exercises, ExerciseVariationRelation.new, child_index: 'NEW_RECORD' do |e| %>
    <%= render "form_variation", form: e %>
   <% end %>

Form_variation
<%= content_tag :div, class: "nested-fields" do %>
<%= form.collection_select(:exercise_variation_id, Exercise.all, :id, :name, {}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
<% end %>
```

I understand how join tables work but this self join/relation is confusing still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your model (at least how it is presented in your question) needs some clarification :) for instance:

- do these relations act like a transitive network? if A is a variation of B and B is a variation of C, does that make A a variation of C?
- if A is a variation of B, does that make B a variation of A?

in the simplest case, this should work i think:

```
create_table :exercise_variations do |t|
    t.references :exercise, foreign_key: true, null: false, index: true
    t.references :variation, foreign_key: { to_table: :exercises }, null: false, index: true 
end

class ExerciseVariation < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :exercise, foreign_key: "exercise_id"
    belongs_to :variation, foreign_key: "variation_id", class_name: "Exercise" 
end

class Exercise < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :exercise_variations, class_name: "ExerciseVariation"
    has_many :variations, through: :exercise_variations
    
    has_many :variation_exercises, foreign_key: :variation_id, class_name: "ExerciseVariation"
    has_many :variations, through: :variation_exercises
end
```

Comment: To answer your question, yes both those points are true. A could very well be a variation of C, furthermore, A being a variation of B, then B would be a variation of A. I played with the code you posted and unfortunately it does not work. While records are stored in the `ExercisesVariation` Table, querying by `@foo.variations` returns an empty collection. It seems the `id` is `nil`  => `SELECT "exercises".* FROM "exercises" INNER JOIN "exercise_variations" ON "exercises"."id" = "exercise_variations"."variation_id" WHERE "exercises"."id" = $1 /* loading for inspect */ LIMIT $2  [["id", nil]`

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'exercise_variation_id' for Exercise.)`

The error message is clearly Exercise doesn't have exercise_variation_id.

Could you show your `app/db/schema.rb` file content?
Make sure your migration creates exercise_variation_id for Exercise in the database.

Comment: Posted an update with schema and foreign keys added. However, my understanding of this whole process is that the `ExerciseVariationRelation` table is to make it so I would not have an `exercise_variation_id` column on the `Exercise` model.

Comment: I was calling the wrong variable for the field simple mistake I was using `:exercise_drills' instead of `:variation_exercises` in the form.